# Attempting to Prove a lower bound for the Binomial Coefficient

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, binomial-coefficients

The inequality I am having a problem with is as follows:

Let $1\leq k\leq n$, where $n,k$ are natural numbers. Prove that $\binom{n}{k}\geq(\frac{n}{k})^k$

I have proven already the inequality $\binom{n}{k}\leq\frac{n^k}{k!}\leq(\frac{en}{k})^k$, but cannot seem to prove my lower bound. I have been told that differentiating may be of use, though I am unsure how to approach this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The ratio of $\binom{n}{k}$ and $\left(\frac nk\right)^k$ can be written as

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\binom{n}{k}}{\left(\frac nk\right)^k}&=\frac{\frac{n!}{n^k\,(n-k)!}}{k!/k^k}\\\\
&=\frac{\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1-\frac{2}{n}\right)\left(1-\frac{3}{n}\right)\cdots\left(1-\frac{k-1}{n}\right)}{\left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)\left(1-\frac{2}{k}\right)\left(1-\frac{3}{k}\right)\cdots\left(1-\frac{k-1}{k}\right)}
\end{align}$$

Inasmuch as $n\ge k$, each term in the numerator $\left(1-\frac{m}{n}\right)$ is greater than the corresponding term $\left(1-\frac{m}{k}\right)$  in the denominator.  Therefore, the ratio is bounded below by $1$ and we are done!

Comment: I believe you have to divide the numerator by $n!$. The numerator you currently have is $\left. {n \choose k} \middle/ {n \choose n-k} \right.$.

Comment: @reneg The ratio is correct.

Comment: @RenéG I've added a line to show that the original development was indeed correct.

Answer (score 2):

Denote $[m]:=\{1,\cdots,m\}$ for integers $m$. The formula $\binom{n}{k}k^k$ counts the set $A$ pairs $(f,X)$ with $X$ a $k$-subset of $[n]$ and $f$ a function $[k]\to[n]$ with range contained in $X$. The formula $n^k$ simply counts the set $B$ of functions $[k]\to[n]$. There is a surjection $A\to B$ given by $(f,X)\mapsto f$.